# how to calculate bitwise operation back

Tags: bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

i want to crypt some informations with bitwise operations.

For example two numbers with bitwise or: 8 and 1 to 9.

But how can i encrypt it it to get my root nombers?

greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bitwise xor to achieve this, it's known as a [xor cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).

Answer (score 3):

OR is not reversible. XOR is reversible.

Answer (score 2):

From all bitwise operations only [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_disjunction) is reversible. Look for [XOR-cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher), the easiest way to encrypt your data.
In your case you still have to know at least one number from both to restore the second one!
There is no way that you can restore both.

Comment: Bitwise operations are binary (except for negation). I am not sure that you want, but if you have 4 numbers you can xor them all with the same 5th number to encode and xor again to decode. Or you need something else?